# C++ string literal data type storage

Tags: c++, memory, compiler-construction, types, storage

```
void f()
{
    char *c = "Hello World!"
}
```

Where is the string stored? What's the property of it? I just know it is a constant, what else? Can I return it from inside of the function body?

Answer (score 22):

it is packaged with your binary -- by packaged I mean hard-wired, so yes you can return it and use it elsewhere -- you won't be able to alter it though, and I strongly suggest you declare it as:

```
const char * x = "hello world";
```

Comment: +1. I doubt it will even compile without the const qualifier.

Comment: I vaguely recall oldschool C compiler profiles refusing to compile without `const`.

Comment: @Rahul G: I learned something today :) (upvote on comment) That's really stupid though...

Comment: @BillyONeal: Like I mentioned below, since the C++ spec AFAIK doesn't state that these have to be read-only, there's no reason it has to be language-enforced as const.

Comment: @Rahul, it does *now*. But C++0x is going to forbid assigning to `char*`. It removed this deprecated conversion from the const literal array to `char*`

Comment: @BillyONeal It does compile but the string const to char * conversion is deprecated. See this online gcc compiler [link](https://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:g447,options:'+-O0',source:'%23include%3Ciostream%3E%0A%23include%3Cstring%3E%0Ausing+namespace+std%3B%0Astring+display()%7B%0A++char*+cstring%3D+%22hell%22%3B%0A++int+a+%3D+sizeof+cstring%3B%0A++string+str%3D%22hel%22%3B%0A++return+%22string%22%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Aint+main()%7B%0A++char+cstring%5B%5D%3D%22hellohello%22%3B%0A++return+0%3B%0A%7D')),filterAsm:(binary:!t,colouriseAsm:!t,commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,labels:!t),version:3).

Answer (score 7):

The string is stored in the data area of the program. This is completely compiler, executable format, and platform dependent. For example, an ELF binary places this in a different location than a Windows executable, and if you were compiling for an embedded platform this data might be stored in ROM instead of RAM.

Here's an illustration of the layout of the ELF format:

[image: ELF Layout]

Your string data would most likely be found in the `.data` or `.text` sections, depending on compiler.

You can certainly return it from inside the function body. Just check with your implementation to verify that it is random access, as many implementations won't let you overwrite it.

Comment: Executable format does not define how string literals are stored.

Comment: It absolutely does. Several executable standards specify where to put static data in the file.

Comment: Hmm.. I'm not aware of any. ELF, PE, and NE certainly don't. PE and ELF formats provide a facility of a string table for localization purposes, but string constants aren't (generally) put there because that's not their purpose.

Comment: While you are correct in your first paragraph (sort of...) about what you are saying, I would not take such a strong stance on things -- "checking with implementation to see weather you can change the const" is very bad advice to give someone. You are suggesting that there might be a C implementation where doing this is OK ---- there isn't and any way of doing it will be a HACK. (I won't -1 though).

Comment: @David: Yes, ELF has .text and .data sections -- but neither section says anything about storing constant string data. A compiler is free to do so, but it's not a standardized part of the format.

Comment: @BillyONeal That's why I said that it is also compiler and platform dependent.

Comment: @HassanSyed +1 for the comment about the bad advice of changing a const.

Answer (score 6):

§2.14.15 String Literals, Section 7

> A narrow string literal has type “array of n const char”, where n is the size of the string as defined below, and has **static storage duration**.

Answer (score 5):

It is generally stored in the read only section of memory and has static storage allocation.

Performing operations like `c[0] = 'k'` etc invokes Undefined Behavior.

> Can I return it from inside of the function body?

Yes!

Answer (score 3):

It has static storage duration, so it exists throughout the life of the program. Exactly where the compiler/linker put initialized data varies. Returning a pointer to it from a function is fine, but be sure you return a `char const *` -- writing to the string causes undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1):

It's implementation defined. Most of the time that would be stored in a string table with all the other strings in your program. Generally you can treat it like a global static const variable except it's not accessible outside your function.

Answer (score 0):

The string literals are stored on DATA segment and allocated at compile time. This helps to assign same string literals to multiple variables without creating copies of string.

e.g char * str="hello";

The str is char pointer, having address of char h, while "hello" is stored in data segment and cannot be altered. Trying to alter it will generate Segmentation fault.

While assigning a char array string literal creates a copy of string on stack.

i.e char str[]="hello";

"hello" is copied to stack (appended by null character) and str points to character 'h' in stack.

Answer (score -3):

It's been a while since I played with C++, but I remember I (self taught) had a load of problems with strings (well, ok, character arrays...).

If you're going to be modifying their value at all, be sure to use the new and delete keywords... Something along these lines...

```
char *strText = new char[10];
/* Do something
...
...
...
*/
delete [] strText;
```

Martin

Comment: You must match `new[]` with `delete[]`, not `delete`. Or just use `std::string`.

Comment: My bad then - couldn't remember having to do that though... Then again, C++ was a long time ago for me - Borland Turbo C++ for MSDOS...

Comment: Some compilers get it right without the square brackets added to `delete`, but I would not rely on it.

Comment: If everyone immediately fixes their answer in the light of comments on SO, the trouble is that the comments will remain, and will cast doubt of the credibility of what would then be the correct answer. Better in my view to just accept that you're wrong (see above) and move on...

Comment: Or if people would fix the answer, it wouldn't be wrong, and then they could add a comment saying "hey thanks for pointing out the mistake, it has been corrected..."

Comment: Gnarf - I have already pointed out that my original answer was wrong - but you have a point. So, anyone reading it now, the answer has been amended accordingly...